# Prove that $f(x)=\frac{x}{\tan x}$ is a decreasing function for $x\in (0,1]$

Tags: inequality

$$f’(x)=\frac{\tan x -x\sec^2x}{\tan^2 x}$$

For it to be a decreasing function
$$\tan x -x\sec^2 x<0$$
$$\sin x\cos x>x$$
$$\implies \sin 2x >\frac x2$$

How do I prove that it this inequality exists for $0<x\le 1$?

Comment: You misteriously reversed the inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{\tan x} \implies f'(x)=\frac{\tan x-x \sec^2 x}{\tan^2 x}=\frac{g(x)}{\tan^2 x}$$
$$g(x)=\tan x-x \sec^2 x \implies g'(x)=\sec^2 x-\sec^2 x-2x\sec x \tan x<0~~if~~ x \in (0,\pi/2)$$
Therefore, $g(x)$ is a decreasing function in $(0, \pi/2) \implies g(x)\le g(0) =0.$
Finally, in $(0, \pi/2) $ $f'(x)<0$, this means $f(x)$ is a decreasing function.

Answer (score 3):

The last line in your calculation is wrong, together with the direction of the inequality sign. You really get

$\Rightarrow \sin 2x< 2x$.

That is, you want $\sin x< x$, which is well-known and simple (for all positive $x$).